# Producing detail level use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case, ooad

Curerntly, I am documenting all the client's requirements using usecase diagrams and ofcourse I am new in design paradigm. I have a highlevel usecase diagram that contain overall system requirements. And then I have detail level usecase diagram for each usecase define in high level usecase diagram. Now, In detail level diagram, I have included usecases that system trigger itself as well.

> e.g. High level usecase - Upload Report file
>
> Detail level usecase for Upload Report file:

[image]

Here, in the figure above, the usecase 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5 are trigger from system and this usecases are not directly interacted with user.

So, my question is that should I include these type of system level usecase in the details usecase diagram or should I just include those usecase that only interact with user?

P.S. if what I'm doing above is not valid(the way I am producing usecase diagram as in diagram displayed) then please I would like to have your recommendations.

Comment: I'd recommend reading Bittner/Spence. You are trying functional decomposition, not creating use cases.

Comment: Okay, thank you for information. I kinda feel that way that use cases that I am producing in some sort of functional way. Anyway, I would be grateful if you could tell me what can I do instead then? Can you please provide me some solution for my case? In the meanwhile, I will study on your recommended book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not really an answer, but an advise. The problem here is that I'd need to dump your design so far and start from scratch. And that's of course not possible. So as a guidance:

- Look for added value, not functionality.
- Do not use (!) include/extend and just draw simple associations between actor and use case.
- For each use case ask yourself: is that added value? Only if the answer is yes, then add the bubble.
- Name each use case with verb/subject (and eventually an object)
- Use only the main actor and leave away any secondary actors in your diagrams.
- If your UC diagrams start resembling spider webs your design is likely broken.
- There is no absolute number, but you end usually with a handful of actors and a few dozen of UCs.

Comment: Your answer is really very clear and informative. Thank you very much.